# Why c++ program with logical and operator and increment operator gives different output than expected?

Tags: c++, operators

I am trying following C code. I my opinion output of this code should be 0 0 0 0. But after executing it output comes as 0 -1 -1 0. Can anybody explain how output comes.

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        int x=-1, y=-1, z=-1;
        int w= ++x && ++y && ++z;
        cout<<x<<" "<<y<<" "<<z<<" "<<w<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: @Stargateur no it is not UB

Comment: There is not UB in this code.

Comment: Your title says this is a C question, yet you tag "c++" (and the code uses `cout`). Maybe you should update your question to say C++ or change the tag if you really are looking for a C solution. C and C++ are *very different* languages - don't mix them up or think they are interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for the save, @haccks Instantly regretted kneejerk close.

Comment: @Slava actually I didn't even read the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the short-circuit behaviour of the `&&` operator. `++x` evaluated to `0` which will be considered as `false`. So, only `++x` will be evaluated and rest expressions will not be evaluated and final value of the expression `++x && ++y && ++z` will be `0` and it will be assigned to `w`.

Comment: This does not explain why `z==0`  I would expect `0 -1 -1 -1`

Comment: @RichardCritten z is -1 w is 0

Comment: Thanks am blind sorry about that.